# How to disable Breadcrumbs on Login page

Tags: angular, spartacus-storefront

I want to hide Breadcrumbs component if I go to the Login page, I can just replace content with empty content:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppLoginFormComponent,
    AppAuthTabsComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.withConfig({
      cmsComponents: {
        ReturningCustomerLoginComponent: {
          component: AppLoginFormComponent,
          disableSSR: true,
        },
        BreadcrumbComponent: {
          component: EmptyContentComponent,
          disableSSR: true,
        },
      }
    } as CmsConfig),
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    I18nModule,
    UrlModule,
    RouterModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FormErrorsModule,
    SharedModule,
  ],
})
export class LoginPageModule { }
```

This approach partially helps, but this approach will also replace this component in whole system.

So, what is the proper way to hide component on concrete page, or even how to add unique customization for it.

Answer (score 2):

The proper way to choose which components are displayed on specified page should be done in sampledata/backoffice, not Spartacus side.

Comment: So in the back-office I can hide BreadcrumbComponent on concrete page? Do I correct? Can you sent the link where I can configure it?

Comment: "The `BottomHeaderSlot` is part of the page content, and has the `BreadcrumbComponent` assigned for each page, expect the home page. This already demonstrates that you can vary to show or hide the component per page.

One potential issue with this approach, is that the page title will be dropped as well. This is an unfortunate consequence how the page title/breadcrumb are tight together...

An alternative solution, that keeps the title, is to override the breadcrumb data on a page resolver specifically for the login page." ~Tobias

Answer (score 0):

Go to `https://localhost:9002/hac/console/impex/import` past next impex, and press `Import Content` button.

```
$contentCatalog=apparel-uk-spaContentCatalog
$contentCV=catalogVersion(CatalogVersion.catalog(Catalog.id[default=$contentCatalog]),CatalogVersion.version[default=Online])[default=$contentCatalog:Online]
$siteResource=jar:de.hybris.platform.spartacussampledata.constants.SpartacussampledataConstants&/spartacussampledata/import/contentCatalogs/apparel-ukContentCatalog

# clear BottomHeaderSlot for home page (replaced by an empty slot)
INSERT_UPDATE ContentSlot;$contentCV[unique=true];uid[unique=true];name;cmsComponents(uid, $contentCV)
;;LoginBottomHeaderSlot;Homepage Bottom Header Slot;

INSERT_UPDATE ContentSlotForPage;$contentCV[unique=true];uid[unique=true];position[unique=true];page(uid,$contentCV);contentSlot(uid,$contentCV)[unique=true]
;;BottomHeaderSlot-login;BottomHeaderSlot;login;LoginBottomHeaderSlot
```

This impex will replace Breadcrumbs on Login page with empty content.